# jQuery AJAX call not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I feel a little silly here. My ajax call is running the error: function every time. I know that the data is coming back as JSON, but i've done the datatype as jsonp to allow for cross origin stuff. I don't think I can do anything differently, unless I'm forgetting something obvious. Please- whats wrong with this:

```
function sartleApi(type,endpoint,object,callback){


 $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type:type,
    data:object,
    url:"http://dev.sartle.com/includes/ajax_reviewcomment.php?rid=1178",
    success:function(data){
        callback(data);
    },

    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: That website doesn't support JSONP.

Comment: edited code to show alerts, come back as follows: success,undefined,200,Error: jQuery183039935008878819644_1374881928941 was not called

Answer (score 2):

Your website doesn't support JSONP.

JSONP is just a fancy way of passing a JSON object to a global callback function via a `<script>` tag. It circumvents cross-origin restrictions by not sending an AJAX request in the first place, but instead creating a `<script>` tag.

A JSON response looks like this:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

But a JSONP response is:

```
some_callback({"foo": "bar"})
```

That PHP script doesn't wrap the JSON response in a callback function (whose name is usually specified via the `callback` GET parameter), so you simply can't make a JSONP request. The request will succeed, but the global callback function will not be called, so you will not be able to use the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

- stlll, it seems a cross-domain issue: please try this library https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js
- as a `jsonp` the result is already a callback function with a javascript object argument. Make sure that the returned function by the server is implemented:
  The server could return `my_callback({...})`. You need to implement `my_callback` function client-side.
- place some alerts/console.log on both `success` and `error` functions. Always make a little debug of your own before posting the issue.
- as posted in the comment: state the return code of the ajax call.

Comment: @AlexNeigher - it is 200 OK .. but no responseText or body?

Comment: @AlexNeigher - try the library posted as 1st point in the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

So, to try to circumvent the cross domain issue, using jSONP turned out to be a bad idea. I'm running these calls from a localhost, so i've changed the url in the ajax call to

`url:"http://localhost/includes/ajax_reviewcomment.php?rid=1178"`

I will build this url to be dynamic so that the current URL always is domain-consistent with the server, and i should be in good shape!

Answer (score -1):

in type you need put "GET" or "POST"

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type:type, <<<<<<------ here 
    data:object,
    url:"http://dev.sartle.com/includes/ajax_reviewcomment.php?rid=1178",
    success:function(data){
        callback(data);
    },

error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

});

}

Comment: this function is wrapped within an apicall() function that assigns type to "GET"

Comment: it is clear that the type comes as a parameter.. so 99% chances it comes with a valid value

Comment: oh yeah, srry for that i didnt see the first line :/